# Proving atleast 1 solution - Optional excercises - calc1

Tags: calculus

I am proving some claims using the intermediate value theorem, and I am kind of stuck on this 1:

$f(x)$ is continuous throughout $\mathbb{R}$.
$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : |f(x)| \le 5$

Prove: the equation $f(x) + 3x = 9$ has at least $1$ solution.

What I tried:

Write differently: $f(x) + 3x - 9 = 0$

$-5 \le f(x) \le 5$            (subtract $9$)
$-14 \le f(x) - 9 \le -4$      (add $3x$)
$-14 + 3x \le f(x) + 3x - 9 \le -4 + 3x$

So I got there , and was trying to somehow prove that $1$ side is positive and $1$ negative to use the theorem, but I can't guarantee that if I choose $x=2$ lets say (to make sure left side negative and right side positive), what $f(x)$ will be.

Please help me proceed

Thank you

Comment: $f(x)+3x \to\infty$ as $x \to \infty$  and $f(x)+3x \to-\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$. Use Intermediate Value Property of continuous functions.

Comment: @geetha290krm I tried another approach. please provide feedback:

g(x) = f(x) -9 + 3x.

-14+3x<=g(x)<=-4+3x.

now i can choose x=2  because the inequality above hold for all R:

...
-8<=g(x)<=2.

Now i can use the theorem?

Comment: No, you only showed that $g$ lies between $-8$ and $2$. You did not prove that the values $-8$ and $2$ are actually attained. What if $g(x)=1$ for all $x$?

Comment: @geetha290krm ohh i see, i will fix it to your solution then.